# Can't install ndiswrapper

Tags: software-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have downloaded `ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz` and I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz
```

and I get this:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
E: It has not been able to locate the package ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz
E: Could not find any package with the regular expression "ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz"
```

I need this to install drivers for my Wireless network card.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Inglés sólo por favor!  Have a look here on [how to install Ubuntu Software if you're a Windows User](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926).

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the downloaded file with the command:

> `tar zxvf ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz`

This will create `ndiswrapper-1.59` directory. Change to that
directory and run

```
  make uninstall
  make
  sudo make install
```

There are more instructions in the `INSTALL` file inside the `ndiswrapper-1.59` directory. You must read them to understand how to use this tool.

Also, I guess there is ndiswrapper package in Ubuntu repo which you can install using:

> `sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common`